# Android app best layout for image buttons?

Tags: android, image, layout

I'm developing a VERY SIMPLE android application that is designed with 5 activites, each with its own RelativeLayout.

1) The Parent (or Home)
2-5) Children of Home which each have their own back buttons, which call finish().

[image: Heres what it the home screen looks like]

**The Problem:**
I'm using image assets everywhere and I have stress tested the application by constantly switching from Parent to Child over and over.  I RUN OUT OF MEMORY due to the age-old **"VM budget exceeded"** error.!

**What I have tried:**
I have tried trimming down the image assets set most of my objects to static references so that they be garbage collected when the Child activity finishes.
I have installed the MAT tool to examine the HPROFS dumps, which was very confusing.
I have read about SoftReferences or WeakReferences and File caching techniques, but have yet to implement them.

**EDITED...here's my onDestroy for each child activity.**

```
@Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        // unbind all drawables starting from the first viewgroup
        unbindDrawables(findViewById(R.id.info_layout));
        c2 = null;
        runnable = null;
        mFont = null;
        root = null;
        myThread = null;
        myImage = null;
        v = null;
        txtCurrentTime = null;
        common = null;
        System.gc();
        Log.e("Info", "Info destroyed.");
    }
```

ALSO...All of these are declared as private at the start of the class declaration.  Do they need to be declared as static or something else?

**The question:**
Is there a different type of layout I could use that wouldnt involve calling finish() on the activities, like TabHost or ViewFlipper something similar...that would prevent me from having to start a new activity and finish it

OR Perhaps...a way that when I call finish() on my Child activities so that everything gets garbage collected?

XML and/or code examples are welcome.

I am open to either, or any other way that could be suggested.

Thanks.
Rick

Answer (score 0):

If you're running OOM after switching from parent to child repeatedly then you're probably leaking the child activity.  I'd run an hprof and make sure that you aren't accumulating child activites, and if you are try to find out what references aren't be freed and make sure they go to null in onDestroy.

This usually happens when the framework has a pointer to your child context that it doesn't get told to release via an unregister, or through a circular reference of some sort in your app, possibly through non-static child classes.

Comment: Added the part where I declare all of them as PRIVATE only with a question - do they need to be declared static or something else?